# Illegal instruction while importing object_detection library

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, object-detection

While importing tensorflow's 'object_detection' library I am getting "Illegal instruction". I know the case when tenorflow spits out "Illegal instruction" it was because of wrong CPU flags like AVX etc. and I had to compile tensorflow from source with proper instruction set. With 'object_detection' it is the same? If yes, where can I find the source code of it?
I am using TF version 2.6.1 with python 3.8.2

Comment: Source code is inside the Object detection API. You can try to follow instructions to install it for using object_detection : https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf2.md

Comment: Unfortunate, I am doing like that from the beginning and no luck to get it working.